# Yii getting model()->findAll() result but not model()->find()

Tags: yii

I have the following code

```
    $result = Department::model()->findAll('department_id=:department_id', array(':department_id'=>1));         
    $departments = chtml::listdata($result,'department_id', 'department_name');
```

and it returns the correct result. I know that we can use the function find() to get a single result but when I try the following code returning result is NULL

```
    $result = Department::model()->find('department_id=:department_id', array(':department_id'=>1));            
    $departments = chtml::listdata($result,'department_id', 'department_name');
```

What is the issue with find() function ?

Thank you

Comment: could you share what exaclty results when findAll()  and find() ?

Comment: The first code (findAll) gives the following result
Array ( [1] => English ) but NULL when I execute the second method (find())

Comment: department_id is primay key ?

Comment: yes ( I would like to know how find method works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CHtml::listData()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail) expects an array for its first argument. The `findAll()` method returns an array of `Department` objects, which is why it works as desired. However, `find()` only returns a single `Department` object.

If you want to force the `listData()` method to work with the results of `find()`, then you need to wrap the result in an array first.

```
$result = Department::model()->find('department_id=:department_id', array(':department_id'=>1));            
$departments = chtml::listdata(array($result),'department_id', 'department_name');
```

Of course, using `listData()` isn't required at all, although it depends on what you are actually trying to accomplish. You can also access the values as follows:

```
$result = Department::model()->find('department_id=:department_id', array(':department_id'=>1));
echo $result->department_id;
echo $result->department_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want single record by id, please try

```
$result = Department::model()->findByPk($department_id, array(':department_id'=>1));
```

This will give you one record with given id.

Comment: Joel said findAll() works , then how it will be primary key ?

Comment: sorry I know this method, but I just want to know how to use the find() method. thanks